# How to update scneraio name from TestRunner class in Karate

Tags: java, karate

Is there a way I can update the Scneario names in Scenario outline from the TestRunner class in Karate Framework? As Scenraio outlines have many tests, I want to print the test name with the scenrio name in the karate report. In order to do that I would like to update the scenario name from TestRunner.
I dont want to go to each feature file and do it manually.

Kindly let me know if this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

In Karate 1.0 you can use placeholders in the title.

```
Scenario Outline: some text and ${variable}
```

And you should be able to set a variable in the feature using multiple options, which you should already be familiar with.

If this is not what you are looking for, consider this as not supported and you are welcome to contribute code. I really don't understand what you mean by "from TestRunner".

Comment: In the test runner, we are deciding which test scenarios to execute. So from there if I can get a handle on the Scnerio name, I should be able to modify that. kindly let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: @SourabhRoy nope, not supported by karate, sounds like you need to write your own testing framework, all the best 